# Resolve third level host names with local bind9 server

Tags: linux, dns

Let's say I have domain name "example.com" registered and managed by domain.com.

I would like to manage domain names as foo.example.com by my own(without external manager). I have a bind9 dns server at "example.com". Can I delegate third level resolution to my server? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I delegate third level resolution to my server?

Yes, assuming your server is visible to all the computers that will need to use it.

> If yes, how?

You delegate a subdomain by creating an NS record in the parent domain's zone file (or equivalent)

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/27142/55524) in serverfault, and a [more detailed explanation](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/delegate.html) at Zytrax (which may be a bit too complicated if you are new to DNS and BIND)

Answer (score 0):

Whoever is managing your domain (domain.com) needs to change their authoritative source to your server. You usually do that by using the domain managers UI one last time. Or you can make a service request to them. I know with Network Solutions you can just use the admin interface to change the primary and secondary name servers to your server.